# find out if all images have class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, class

HTML :

```
<div class="regform"><input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required><h3 class="check"><img src=''/></h3></div>
<div class="regform"><input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required><h3 class="check"><img src=''/></h3></div>
<div class="regform"><input id="password2" type="password" name="password2" placeholder="Re password" required><h3 class="check"><img src=''/></h3></div>
<div class="regform"><input id="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required><h3 class="check"><img src=''/></h3></div>
```

JS :

```
        $('#send').click(function(){
    var classs = $(".check").find('img');
    if(classs.hasClass("yes")){
        alert("Everything is correct");
    }else{
        alert("Something is wrong");
    }

});
```

I want to check, if all ".check" images have class "yes".

Comment: In your HTML, no image has the `yes` class. Is that intended ?

Answer (score 7):

```
var dotheyallhavetheclass = $('.check img:not(.yes)').length===0;
```

Answer (score 0):

.......or.............

```
var dotheyallhaveyesclass = (($('img.check').length == $('img.yes').length)) ? 1 : 0);
```

Comment: This considers *all* elements having `check` or `yes`, even those not relevant, e.g. `<div class="yes">Not relevant</div>`

Comment: According to the OP's HTML, there are no irrelevant `.yes` elements. But if it helps, I'll modify my answer.

Comment: You're right, it's just me nitpicking. Unfortunately the HTML and the question don't agree. The structure seems to be `.check img`/`.check img.yes`, not `img.check`.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Yeah, I noticed that. I'm afraid he might run into problems no matter what solution he picks since his markup and his question are not related.

Answer (score 0):

This is pure Javascript solution: The following demo: http://jsbin.com/ucoPEBEv/1/

```
e = document.getElementsByClassName('check');
error = false;
for (j = 0; j < e.length; j++){
   imgs = e[j].getElementsByTagName('img');    
      for (i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++){
          if (imgs[i].className != 'yes'){
             error = true;
             break; 
           } 
      }
  }
if (error){
      alert('Some Thing Wrong');
    }
else{
      alert('Every Thing Well!');
    }
```